# Pandas str instances into one big list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, text-mining

I have a data frame where one column is a sentence for each instance. I would like to take each instance, take out stop words, and put it end-to-end as a string. Any python/pandas thoughts?

Thank you to all of you amazing SQL people who reply - I know I need to learn sql. Right now, I'm just looking for a python/pandas/nltk solution.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for info on posting good questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nltk` for a pre-existing set of stopwords, and then perform a columnwise operation, followed by using `sum` to concatenate strings.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


st_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
dfrm = pd.DataFrame({
    'sentence_index': range(3),
    'sentence': ['the first sentence in the list',
                 'a second sentence in the list',
                 'this is the third sentence']
})
one_big_sentence = dfrm['sentence'].map(
    lambda s: ' '.join(
        [w for w in word_tokenize(s) if w not in st_words]
    ) + ' '
).sum()
print(one_big_sentence)
```

Note that you'll need to have executed `nltk.download()` in advance and downloaded both the `stopwords` corpus and the `punkt` tokenizer model, for the above code to work. Otherwise you may get errors related to `nltk` inability to find necessary data.

When I run the above program, here is the output:

```
$ python sentence.py 
first sentence list second sentence list third sentence
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Ely. I knew that nltk has the stop words. But I didn't know when/if to apply prior to or after turning that column into text.

Comment: You might want to experiment. Sometimes execution of `lambda` along a pandas column can be inefficient, since it reverts to native Python looping instead of performing more optimized contiguous memory operations along the column. It can't optimize for a `lambda` because it could represent any type of crazy processing. Given this, in some cases it will surely be faster to convert to a string first and then apply the tokenization and filtering. My answer is just meant to demonstrate the operations at a high level, not to be used an any example of what could be optimal in your case.

Comment: Also take care in case you need to perform lowercasing, remove punctuation, or other text preprocessing steps for real data.

Comment: Holy crap. Thank you so much. You answered a totally separate question I had. I'm new to data analysis, and while I love to use lambda, I was trying to figure out why it seemed sooooo sluggish.

Comment: Fast operations along a pandas column will exploit the ability to treat it like a low-level array of data: contiguous in memory and always having the same data type. Then it can hand off the function call, for example like `sum` on a bunch of floating point values, to some specialized, internal C function that by-passes most of the Python interpreter's overhead. It is possible to write functions like that yourself using extension library tools like Cython, or writing them in C. But most often you use ones that are built into pandas, numpy, etc., by the library developers, who are skilled at it

Comment: When the data type along a column is not conducive to an optimized memory representation (for example, the data types are mixed, or the data types are `object` or some custom user-defined type, etc.), and also when the function itself is a high-level, Python function that cannot make assumptions about operating on low-level memory representations, then pandas "falls back" to plain old for-loop iteration and function application, which incurs extra costs of the Python interpreter upon each function execution (each iteration along the column).